# SignalR restore connection

Tags: signalr

how do I restore connection *without refreshing the client app browser* if the backend server goes down, and comes back up in 5min or so...

```js
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                .withUrl(`/place/${props.match.params.id}`)
                .withAutomaticReconnect()
                .build();
                connection.onreconnecting(function() {
                    setError('connection lost..');
                    var reconnectionInterval = setInterval(() => {
                        if (connection.state == signalR.HubConnectionState.Disconnected) {
                            connection.stop();
                            
                                try {
                                    console.log('try to reconnect');
                                    connection.start();
                                } catch (e) {
                                    //doesn't go here, how to handle if the server still down
                                    console.log('failed to reconnect');
                                }
                            
                        }
                    }, 5000);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
if (connection.state == signalR.HubConnectionState.Disconnected) {
                    connection.start()
                        .then(x => {
                            clearInterval(reconnectionInterval);
                            setError(null);
                        })
                        .catch(ex => setError('still disconnected'));
                }
```